# PHP Undefined variable in while loop

Tags: php, loops

**Problem**

While I am fetching information from mysql, I also want to check that some specify column in mysql row is 0.

But then I get the notice Undefined Variabe yet the code works?

**Code**
Line 157:

```
        while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC  ) && $row['status'] == 0) {
```

**Error I get**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\admin\index.php on line 157
```

***My question***:

How do I get rid of that error without creating a if statement under the while loop? I basically want it to handle this in the while loop, if I am not doing that wrong?.

Is using a if statement under the while loop better than using it in the while loop?

What is causing the error? I am already defining what $row is before the && row['status'] == 0.

Thanks

Comment: before the while loop assign null to $row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
while(($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC  )) && $row['status'] == 0)
```

Comment: Oh I get this now.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another possibility is to replace `&&` with `and`, it has other precedence rules. (Although parentheses are much clearer and I always use them around assignments in statements, but that's because of modern C compiler rules which don't apply here)